# How to reset root password on openwrt like embedded linux

Tags: linux, passwords, root, router, openwrt

Yesterday I did one stupid thing. Removed encoded root password from /etc/shadow on my router.

```
root::17459:0:99999:7:::
```

Router firmware is a openwrt like embeded linux with ssh access. 
Now I can't login with neither empty password nor old password.
Is any way to restore password or is updating firmware will reset password ?

Comment: Is there another user on the system? Can you ssh in to that user and do `sudo su` to get to a root prompt and change the password from there?

Comment: No. Root is the only available user

Comment: Do you have access to modify the kernel command line arguments? (e.g: U-Boot)

Comment: No. I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

**There's a [failsafe mode](https://mkunc.com/2014/04/02/how-to-reset-openwrt-root-password/) which can be used to reset the root password on OpenWrt**. It brings the router up in logged-in-to-root state. This worked for me with OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment 12.09 when I didn't have the root pw on a TP-Link TL-WR841ND. Maybe it will work for you or others who come looking for this info:

- Power cycle router
- Wait for the DMZ light (second left -- only one on beside "power") start blinking -- the normal boot process
- Hold router reset button for 2 seconds
  (light stops, then resumes blinking, rapidly)
- Plug into router WAN port (failsafe unavail from LAN ports)
- Set computer's IP addr to 192.168.1.2, netmask 255.255.255.0, GW 192.168.1.1
  (I was on a Mac, so did: `sudo ifconfig en10 inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0`.  My ethernet was on interface `en10`.  The link at the top includes some info for Windows users, but I can't test this right now.)
- `telnet` to 192.168.1.1.  It should connect, and give you a banner, drink recipe and root prompt.
- `mount_root` to mount router’s filesystem in read/write mode
- `passwd` to change root password

Now, you can reboot the router again, and try it out.  Don't forget to change your computer's ethernet interface back to using DHCP (I did `sudo ipconfig set en10 DHCP`), and plug into a LAN port.  Then you can visit the router at its normal address (mine was http://192.168.55.1/) and login using the password you set.

Comment: Openwrt [no longer ships with telnet](https://git.archive.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt.git;a=commit;h=4f7b2d42572ce72a90f3dd7e82ccc45c5fc7f871), but you can use ssh without a password to get to 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a restore factory or reset available, it should take you back to default configuration (in most routers admin:admin)

Comment: This answer is a stab in the dark and does not address the issue.